# What is the difference between writing and writing with flush?

Tags: java, netty, nio

Recently I was experimenting with netty. I came across the following problem:

`ctx.channel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame("hello"))` didnot return *hello* on the client side, but `ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("hello"))` did.

What is the difference between two ? `ctx` is the `ChannelHandlerContext`.

Comment: In general, write might buffer somedata before flushing it. Write and flush means to put data into stream without buffering it. When sending much data buffering is usually faster.

Comment: well, only "write" never helped the data to be sent in my case.

Comment: You need to flush the data always even if you use write() then after you write you should do ctx.channel().flush().  Whatever is left in the buffer will be flushed (sent).

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud data usually will be flushed if: 1. You manually request it (using flush method), 2. Buffer reaches it limits and therefor to get more data it need push it out first. Of course this is the basic, some sophisticated implementations might check that computer is in idle and because it does nothing it's good occasion to flush buffer. There might be other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 4):

According to doc

http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html

```
  channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
```

is a shortcut for

```
  channel.write(msg);
  channel.flush();
```

And `flush()` *flushes* (*writes down*) all the pending buffers.

Comment: so pending buffers always remain pending if I don't flush ?

Comment: @Md. Arafat Al Mahmud: no the don't; but it's *system* to decide when the buffers should be actually written down.

Comment: I understand. But I am not sure if netty itself overrides the general buffering mechanism.

Comment: @Md. Arafat Al Mahmud: Time to time we have to insist - "put down the data to file, channel etc. as early as possible, the other software is waiting" or "we're in a deadly crash, try al least to write down the buffer for us to inspect"

Answer (score 1):

The way I think it works is if you use write and you are sending more data than the buffer can hold it will automatically flush when the buffer is full to make room for more data to be buffered.  At the end when there is no more data to push the other data through the buffer you must call flush() to flush whatever is left in the buffer.  In your case what you are sending does not excede the buffer size so it sits in the buffer and nothing pushes it through that is why you must call flush() after write to push whatever is left in the buffer through.  The writeAndFlush method does this automatically for you I think when it reaches the end it automatically flushes the buffer.

Comment: That is making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly in Netty `write()` buffers and `flush()` flushes. Exactly as in a `BufferedOutputStream`, in fact.

So the question arises: when to `flush()`? The answer is, at the end of sending a request or a response, unless you're about to close the channel. For example, in a client,merits all the request karts, flush, then read the response. In a server, send all the response parts, and flush.

Comment: That's slightly s incorrect. It is up to the implementation of your `OutputHandler` how that is handled. Most `write()` operations in Handlers are immediate, but some, such as [the one for chunked http](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.java#L129) just add the writes to a queue. Only flushing will actually flush the queue.